# Is random loot related to damage done/killing blow?

Tags: diablo-iii

I am struggling with finding good items. I am wondering if it is because I play the game all wrong.

I have around 400k damage and play at Torment I/II/III. At level II & III I do very little damage to the enemies and I tend to just follow my more powerful friends around, like a leech feeding on their kills.

Does this strategy mean that I get less good items? Are items based on how much damage I do towards an enemy, or if I am the player killing it, or does D3 treat it equally?

Comment: bear in mind that (with the exception of some torment-only items) drops are not related to difficulty level. So face-rolling normal results in a lot more dice-rolls per minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Item drops are just based on your presence when the enemies die. Even if you don't contribute at all, you will still get the same drops, so long as you are nearby when the enemy dies.

Comment: It's even less demanding than that. I remember a few times I ported from a camp to one of the players, just to find a star on the minimap and a legendary drop waiting for me. It must have dropped from a mob killed when I wasn't around.

Comment: @ykb This loot might have come from a chest. The chest loot is not proximity-related. You wont get any loot from trashmobs/elite/purple/goblin if you are far when the mob is killed, but the loot from chest always drop even if you are not on the same map a the moment the chest was open. So a bit of advice when you split farm, always go tab-check the map other player cleared just to see if you missed a Legendary

Comment: @WizLiz Ah that must've been it, then. Thanks for clearing it up, and for a good advice!

Comment: This makes a lot sense and when I think about it, I've seen this too. Thanks for replying :)